# Change background image of button in List view which is offscreen?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have a list view with an image, a textview and a button at the end. The button basically has 3 states which i represent using images. 
What I want to do is change the background of button which is clicked and change the background of other buttons in the list view according to their current states.

Workaround I used is I changed the background image of buttons according to their states and then finish() the activity and restarted it. This shows the activity start animation which is annoying. It creates problems with buttons offscreen.

Is there anyway to change the background image of buttons offscreen listview inside onClick of any button in List View row ??